# 502 Bad Gateway when switching rails app to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I have an issue when trying to deploy my rails app in production mode on my server using phusion passenger with nginx.

My app runs perfectly fine in development mode, with this configuration file :

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name domain.co;
 root /home/me/projects/myapp/public;
 passenger_enabled on;
 rack_env development;
}
```

What I did is simply switch the **development** with **production**.

When I do this, I simply get a "502 Bad Gateway" message.
A production.log file is created, but it is 0 bytes.

I could not find any other log that indicate whether there is an issue or not (nothing else in the log folder, nothing in /etc/var/nginx/. . .).

When I try to run **passenger-status** in my project structure, passenger tells me it is not running here. I get a proper status message when I do the same thing in development mode.

My guess is that passenger tries to start the app but something fails early in the process; the issue is that I can't get to know why because I am unable to find any log.

I have found several other questions on Stack Overflow about the same problem, but most of them get some kind of log. I guess if I could get access to the error message somehow that would help.

Is there anything obvious I miss? 
Thanks, 
Julien

Comment: Just try this:

    server {
        listen 80;
        root /home/me/projects/myapp/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_app_env production;
    }

Answer (score 0):

And as usual, Stack Overflow is great for rubber duck debugging and now I feel extremely stupid.

The issue seems to come from the fact that I put my **SECRET_KEY_BASE** environment variable in the **.bashrc** file; which doesn't work on my production environment. 
If I put the export statement in **~/.rvm/environment/ruby***** instead, everything works fine. . .